# How to change Odoo Logo on POS - Odoo 16 installed on Docker?

Tags: postgresql-13, odoo-16

I try to find the location of the Odoo logo on POS, but I could not find it any where in my VPS.

Search the answer online and found out that I could change it in location, but I have not found the directory yet. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

~/odoo/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/img/logo.png

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain which logo you are referring to ?

~/odoo/addons/point_of_sale/static/src/img contains logo.png which is a white logo of the odoo brand

~/odoo/addons/point_of_sale/static/description/ contains icon.png which is the icon you see in the app list for the POS app